# C++ User entered string must be in DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: c++, date

I'm fairly new to C++ and my prof gave us an assignment, part of which is the following instruction:

**Ask user to enter a date in this format:** dd-mm-yyyy.
**Check if user’s entry is correct - it must be 10 characters long, the 3rd and the 5th characters must be dashes and all other characters must be digits from 0 to 9. If a single error is found, print a message and ask for a new entry.**

This is the code I have so far. That's as far as I got. *I don't know how to check the string for 'dashes' at specific positions in the string*. I don't need the solution written out for me, any documentation or example would be fine. I searched both google and stackoverflow for an answer, but all I found were PHP or C# answers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const int datelength = 10;
    string date;

    cout << "Enter a date using the DD-MM-YYYY format: ";
    cin >> date;

    if (date.size() > datelength) {

        cout << "\n\nYour entry must be 10-char long. Hit any key to continue..." << endl << endl;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `date.size() != dateLength`, `date[2] == '-'` `date[5] == '-'` etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja can you explain what this code here does `date.size() != dateLength` ? Also is that line of code the If Condition?

Comment: It checks if the length is not the same as what you want. Your code checks for a larger string but not a smaller one.

Comment: Hint: `strptime`. Is `99-99-9999` or `00-00-0000` valid by that definition?

Comment: @tadman No. It has to be a valid date, for example `dd` can't be **45** because day can only be 1 to 31 (but i don't think it matters that month has 30 or 31 or 28 days). But the date can be 20-03-2050.

Comment: First, check the length of the string, using the `std::string::length()` method.  Next, verify that the separators are in the correct positions.  Finally, you can use `std::istringstream` the numbers from the string and verify them.

Comment: See [`std::get_time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

Comment: @Cereal You'll need to use a date parsing function to validate this or you'll have things like `29-02-2011` being presumed valid, which they're not.

Answer (score 1):

You can index into a `string` to access the individual characters, so if I wanted to see if the first character of a string was a `J`, I could do something like this:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);

if (input[0] == 'J')
    std::cout << "It's a J";
```